# Android webview onConsoleMessage error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Tags: javascript, android, webview, android-webview

I am loading a URL in Android webView, it works good on Custom Tab or phone's browser, but not work in webView

when it loads in webView, there is a error printed in `onConsoleMessage()`

error message: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`

sourceId: `https://resources.company.com/client/v2/builds/runtime.48bbfd5a1a8282719421.js`

```
 // webview settings:

   webview.settings.apply {
        setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    }
    webview.addJavascriptInterface(
        WebViewInterface { navigateToPage() },
        "android"
    )
    webview.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient()

    webview.webChromeClient = object : WebChromeClient() {
        override fun onProgressChanged(view: WebView, newProgress: Int) {
            if (newProgress >= PROGRESS_COMPLETE) {
                loading_indicator.hideLoading()
            }
            super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress)
        }

        override fun onConsoleMessage(consoleMessage: ConsoleMessage?): Boolean {
            consoleMessage?.apply {
                Log.d("error test:",  "-- ${message()}--")
            }
            return true
        }
    }
```